# Babylonian square root algorithm - initial guess value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I was looking for Babylonian square root algorithm written in JavaScript, and found this working solution:

```
function sqrt(num) {
  var accuracy = 0.000001;

  function isPrecise(estimation) {
    if (Math.abs( Math.pow(estimation, 2) - num ) < accuracy) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  function improvePrecision(estimation) {
    return (estimation + (num / estimation)) / 2;
  }

  function iteration(estimation) {
    if(isPrecise(estimation)) {
      return estimation;
    } else {
      return iteration(improvePrecision(estimation));
    }
  }

  return iteration(num);
}
```

But I can't see where is initial guess (in code - `estimation`) value is defined. So how it works, when there is no guess value on first iteration? Actually, this value should be eaqual to `num` argument.

Comment: Pass the function argument in as the first guess.  It's the caller that does it.

Comment: The implementation looks ok for reasonable number ranges of `num`. But I bet it will give poor results or run indefinitely for very small numbers (1e-20), very big numbers (1e20), zero, or negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `estimation` is defined inside of the iteration function.

When the function runs the first time, the iteration function is called with the `num` parameter, `return iteration(num)`.

Inside `iteration` function, the algorithm first checks if the estimation is ok.

If not, `iteration` is called again, but this time, it first improves the given `estimation`

`return iteration(improvePrecision(estimation));`

So `iteration` is recursive function, which will call itself unless the estimation is precise enough: (`isPrecise(estimation)`)